# How do I generate row-specific means in a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm looking to generate means of ratings as a new variable/column in a data frame. Currently every method I've tried either generates columns that show the mean of the entire dataset (for the chosen items) or don't generate means at all. Using the rowMeans function doesn't work as I'm not looking for a mean of every value in a row, just a mean that reflects the chosen values in a given row. So for example, I'm looking for the mean of 10 ratings:

```
fun <- mean(T1.1,T2.1,T3.1,T4.1,T5.1,T6.1,T7.1,T8.1,T9.1,T10.1, trim = 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I want a different mean printed for every row because each row represents a different set of observations (a different subject, in my case). The issues I'm looking to correct with this are twofold: 1) it generates only one mean, the mean of all values for each of the 10 variables, and 2) this vector is not a part of the dataframe. I tried to generate a new column in the dataframe by using "exp$fun" but that just creates a column whose every value (for every row) is the grand mean. Could anyone advise as to how to program this sort of row-based mean? I'm sure it's simple enough but I haven't been able to figure it out through Googling or trawling StackOverflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out an answer without a reproducible example but have you tried subsetting your dataset to only include the 10 columns from which you'd like to derive your means and then using an apply statement? Something along the lines of `apply(df, 1, mean)` where the first argument refers to your dataframe, the second argument specifies whether to perform a function by rows (1) or columns (2), and the third argument specifies the function you wish to apply?